# Привязка анимации WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

### Стараюсь реализовать паттерн MVVM, получилось привязать все данные и все функции кроме тех что отвечают за анимацию.

Существует Frame

```
<Frame Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
       Grid.Row="3" 
       Content="{Binding ActuallyBottom, Mode=TwoWay}"
       BorderThickness="0"
       Name="Bot">

    <Frame.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">

            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="60">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                     From="0"
                                     To="60"
                                     Duration="0:0:0:1.5"
                                     DecelerationRatio="1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>

        </EventTrigger>
    </Frame.Triggers>
</Frame>
```

Существует кнопка

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Click="SkipBot" 
        BorderThickness="0"
        Background="#36393E"/>
```

И конечно функция

```
private void SkipBot(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation animation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();
    animation.From = Bot.ActualHeight;
    animation.To = (Bot.ActualHeight == 0) ? 60 : 0;
    animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    Bot.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animation);
}
```

### Как реализовать анимацию по нажатию с помощью привязки?

Возможно у фрейма есть какое-нибудь свойство? Или работа с анимацией отличается?

Comment: `Xaml`. Тригеры, стили, шаблоны, анимация - всё это компетенция вьюхи. Так что все задается в `xaml`.

Comment: Анимация и не должна управляться из VM, она как бы чисто вопрос отображения.

Comment: А чем текущий вариант не устраивает? MVVM, в принципе, он не нарушает. Ну и у `EventTrigger` обратите внимание на свойство `SourceName`, оно позволяет реагировать на события в другом контроле